# Mac OS Message App Badge - "mark as read" shortcut?

Tags: macos, messages, notifications

Is there a way to remove the red Mac OS Message app badge without having to open the app and click on the message? I've looked through settings, preferences, etc... but the only thing I found is the ability to set "do not disturb", which is not what I want.

Details:

Here's one (of many) cases where the badge is unwanted. Each time I get a google verification code I see a notification at the upper right of my screen, giving me time to note the code so I can enter it. I want that, but I don't want the red badge on the message app (see image).

[image]

I know that that badge is from the notification I just received and want to make it disappear -- but the only way I know to do that is to open the Message app and open the message as if I'm reading it. Seems so unnecessary yet I can't figure out how to stop it. I can't use Message's "Do Not Disturb" feature since google uses a different number every time.

If there's no way to avoid this, I'd want, for example, to set up a "mark as read" keyboard shortcut

Comment: When I get that kind of 2FA notification, it also pops a drop menu under the appropriate field on the web page with 'Enter code *abcdef*?'. Acknowledging that sends the verification through to the site & simultaneously marks the message as read.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, but that would only apply to the notification example I gave, which is only "one (of many) cases" as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: How about switching your notifications from banners to alerts, then you'll have a 'done' button.

Comment: @Tetsujin it won't be "done", rather "mark as read" but it gets the job done. I always prefer marking messages read on Mac, than to read on the iPhone.

Comment: As @ankii says Alerts present an "Actions" button that when clicked has a "Mark as Read" submenu. This is not exactly what I asked for, but does mean fewer clicks so I appreciate the help. There seems no way to make a shortcut for that "Mark as Read" submenu. Similarly, within the Messages App there's a "Mark All Messages as Read" submenu available upon right-clicking an unopened message, but making a shortcut for it would be pointless even if possible since you'd have to switch to the app, so there's no saving of clicks. Sigh. There appears no real solution to my 1st world problem.